# Making abstract an overridden method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, abstract

Here's something I quite understand:

```
abstract class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}

abstract class B extends A {
    @Override
    public abstract void foo();
    
    public void bar() {
        super.foo();
        foo();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("c");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new C().foo();
    new C().bar();
}
```

`new C().foo()` prints `c` to the console, while `new C().bar()` prints `a` then `c`.

Calling `super.foo()` is illegal in the `#foo()` implementation of the `C` class.

I don't have a clear question, but if anyone could give a complete explanation of what is going on with the `foo` method, it may be interesting I think.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is super class for `B`, so calling `super.foo()` inside `B` calls method defined in `A`, and calling `foo()` inside the same class will invoke its own implementation that should be delivered by any subclass.

You cannot use `super.foo()` within `C` class because it is defined as `abstract` in `B` and cannot be invoked directly.